# Why REPLACE query is taking so much time in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replace

I Have a SQL query which converts the date time to *106 format* and after that I am replacing the blank space to `-` which takes too much time almost 4 min while executing . Example as follows

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),106),' ','-') DDate
```

> Output 19-Feb-2015

Without replace my query is taking 0 second

Is there any another way to get the custom format dates as mentioned above ?
I understood that `REPLACE` will compare the collection of result items.
But it should not take 4 min to replace 100 to 200 data.

Any thoughts?

Query as

```
SELECT  TOP(ISNULL(100,'10000'))
         FD.Flight 'Select'
        ,FD.Filename    
        ,ISNULL(FD.RefNo, 'FLT-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, FD.FLID)) 'FlightID'                     
        ,FD.Registration
        ,ISNULL(FD.FlightNumber, '') FlightNumber
        **,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,FD.TKD,106),' ','-') TODate**
        ,FD.TOGMT   
        **,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,FD.LKD,106),' ','-') LDDate**
        ,FD.LDGMT
        ,FD.Origin
        ,FD.Destination
        ,FD.Pilot
        ,FD.CoPilot             
        **,REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,FD.DumpDate,106),' ','-') DDate**
        ,FD.UserName
        ,FD.FlightCount     
        ,FD.AcVariation     
    FROM 
        dbo.vw_FlightDetails FD
        LEFT JOIN [dbo].FlightRemark RM ON RM.FlightID = FD.FLID
    WHERE 
        1=1 
    ORDER BY 
         FD.TKD DESC
        ,FD.TOGMT DESC
```

Bold Area is the problem i am facing

Comment: Which version of sql server ? Because there is `FORMAT` function for Sql Server 2012 and above.

Comment: I doubt that this is caused by the `replace()` call. You have to show us the *complete* query - ideally including the definition of all tables involved as `create table` statements and the execution plan with and without the `replace()` call.

Comment: I dont think this is caused by replace

Comment: Its sql SERVER 2008 version.

Comment: I tried the other way means without using the REPLACE function .its taking only 0 second .. do you guys want me to give the full query ?

Comment: Dear all i Have updated above with my question

Comment: Is vw_FlightDetails a view? Is TKD / LKD / DumpDate computed within the view? can you add the view definition as well if its a view.

Comment: Yes vw_FlightDetails  is a view but , These Dates are not computed dates . its just a Date time column in the table and selecting that particular value

Comment: You need to show the actual execution plan for both before and after to see where the difference is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what's happening here, but you can try this:

```
select  <all your _other_ columns>,
        ISNULL(x.RefNo, 'FLT-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.FLID)) FlightID,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.TKD, 106),' ','-') TODate,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.LKD, 106),' ','-') LDDate,
        REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, x.DumpDate, 106),' ','-') DDate,
  from (
      SELECT TOP (ISNULL(100,'10000'))
             FD.Flight 'Select'
            ,FD.Filename    
            ,FD.RefNo, 
            ,FD.FLID
            ,FD.Registration
            ,ISNULL(FD.FlightNumber, '') FlightNumber
            ,FD.TKD                
            ,FD.TOGMT   
            ,FD.LKD
            ,FD.LDGMT
            ,FD.Origin
            ,FD.Destination
            ,FD.Pilot
            ,FD.CoPilot             
            ,FD.DumpDate
            ,FD.UserName
            ,FD.FlightCount     
            ,FD.AcVariation     
        FROM 
            dbo.vw_FlightDetails FD
            LEFT JOIN [dbo].FlightRemark RM ON RM.FlightID = FD.FLID
        WHERE 
            1=1 
        ORDER BY 
             FD.TKD DESC
            ,FD.TOGMT DESC    
    ) x
```

basically, bury the query into a subquery, then format the dates only on the resulting rows.  I suspect this is happening because of the top() statement... it is probably processing many more rows with the REPLACE than it needs to.

Comment: Hey Chris , Thank you for the reply, I have tried the code which you have given but its all the same again 4 min with REPLACE with out that 0 sec.